# Taxonomy terms as arguments to an entity-reference view

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a two content types that are classified by terms of a certain vocabulary.

The first content references another by an entity reference field (auto-complete).

What I need is as following:

When I'm creating the first content type, I choose a taxonomy term from the term reference to classify the content.

Then the entity reference field only show the nodes that are classified by the selected term (the entity reference is being filtered by a view to show the nodes of the second content type).

Does anyone has a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) may help you. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... gives [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) fields an option to populate other form fields with data from selected referenced entities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Reference field option limit](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module yet?

I think it's exactly what you're looking for.  If you have two content types that both share the same term reference field, this module can be used to limit the entity reference field's list to those nodes that share the same term value as the current node...

Let us know if it works for you!

Comment: Dear Boriana, i have tested the module as soon as you posted the solution, and it would solve the problem if both content shared the same term reference field. The only problem is that Content Type 1 can select multiple terms of the vocabulary and Content Type 2 can select only one, so Fields force me to create two separate reference fields. It would be nice if the entity-reference view that filters the node-reference to Content 2 could accept the terms from the taxonomy reference has arguments. Thank you anyway, the solution will be useful for another features.

Comment: Ah yes, I see your issue.  I'm not certain what I'd do in that circumstance.  Hopefully someone else will chime in!